# Unable to get DLookup value with variable field

Tags: vba, ms-access, userform

I have a userform in Access with name BAF_User with 2 fields (BAFUser, BRID).

I am using the below code to get windows username and then compare it using DLookup and get the Full Name of the user who has logged into the Access file.

```
Option Compare Database

Public Function GetUserName() As String
 Dim wshNet As Object
 Dim  As String
 Set wshNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
 GetUserName = wshNet.UserName
 Set wshNet = Nothing
 MyName = DLookup("[BAFUser]", "BAF_User", "[BRID] = '" & GetUserName & " '")
End Function

Private Sub Form_Load()
 MsgBox "Welcome" + MyName
End Sub
```

But this is not showing the value, I am unable to catch what I have done wrong.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Note that you have a relevant space here: `& " '")`. That means your lookup will only return matching usernames + a trailing space.

Comment: thanks, I have removed the space its still not working  
 `MyName = DLookup("[BAFUser]", "BAF_User", "[BRID] = '" & GetUserName & "'")`

Comment: If you are going to set a global variable, might as well use a Sub instead of Function. Where do you declare the global variable MyName? You have a Dim statement with no variable named. That should not even compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use global variable? Just call the function and have it return value.

```
Public Function GetUserName() As String
 Dim wshNet As Object
 Set wshNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
 GetUserName = DLookup("[BAFUser]", "BAF_User", "[BRID] = '" & wshNet.UserName & "'")
 Set wshNet = Nothing
End Function

Private Sub Form_Load()
 MsgBox "Welcome " & GetUserName
End
```

An alternative:
`MsgBox "Welcome " & DLookup("[BAFUser]", "BAF_User", "[BRID] = '" & Environ("USERNAME") & "'"`

Comment: I need to get this value in my other forms too, is there a way to call this function in another forms to get value, instead of writting the full code ?

Comment: The function can be placed into a general module then it would be available from anywhere in the db. Do not give the module same name as function. In my app, I set a textbox on main menu form with the user's name. The form never closes so instead of calling function I just refer to textbox.

Comment: But will it work with my app since I have multiple users using same file same time via shared drive. It can be a possibilty that values may get overwritten when other user opens the file.

Comment: I use this in a split db. The backend is on network server. Each user runs their own copy of the frontend.

Comment: but I have limited access, hence I would not be able to do that.